# PgAdmin for the connection I got error lost ssh-agent error

Tags: postgresql, ssh, proxy, pgadmin, tunnel

I've configured connection, but I always get lost ssh-agent. The database can only through proxy connected.

Can I somewhere see the detailed error, what does it means really lost ssh-agent.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I run pgAdmin as administrator. Then it works.